# Edit a .exe.config.deploy file with C#

Tags: c#, wpf, connection-string, configurationmanager

I've published my WPF app and instead of a .exe.config file, I got a .exe.config.deploy file, since my app is going to be installed only by a browser.

When, the problem is that I need to connect WPF to a remote server, and the IP of the server may change. My question is: How can I edit .exe.config.deploy file to change the connectionString? I can't use ConfigurationManager because of .deploy extension. I've tried using xml editing but then I got an error executing the WPF saying that the config hash does not mach the one at the manifest.

So, what should I do?
Thanks

Comment: Is it installed by `ClickOnce` by any chance? If so, look here: http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2009/08/19/where-do-i-put-my-data-to-keep-it-safe-from-clickonce-updates/

Answer (score 0):

You can edit it, but you will need to re-sign the application to update the hash's and all that jazz.